# List OneDrive directory contents without recursing into subdirectories

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, onedrive

Since Microsoft in those days is giving away [100GB](http://goo.gl/Yc2zfo) + [100GB](https://preview.onedrive.com/bonus) and I've got some GBs free for a few years I tought of using this space as a media storage directory for files downloaded from my VPS.

[image: 215GB]

So I started reading the [OneDrive REST Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659752.aspx) for authenticate myself using `Node.JS` and I did it successfully.

I'm able to:

- Login and access whenever I want (using Access Tokens and Refresh Tokens)
- Upload, edit, remove a file
- Create, edit, remove a directory
- List a directory content

All of this by using the REST API.

The problem is that due to some rescrition of these OneDrive REST APIs I have to cycle through directories to detect their contents (making N calls, depending on the depth of the folder) instead of requesting one single time the desired directory.

I'm just trying to develop a `ls` like command for OneDrive to complete my VPS-OneDrive sync project.

This is my code so far:

```
function lsdir(path, originalpath, folder, callback) {
    dirs = path.split("/");
    if (folder == null) {
        originalpath = path;
        request("https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive?access_token=" + at, function(err, res, body) {
            var json = JSON.parse(body);
            var upload_location = json.upload_location;

            request(upload_location + "?access_token=" + at, function(err, res, body) {
                //console.log(body);
                json = JSON.parse(body);
                var found = false;
                if (originalpath == "/") {
                    callback(json, originalpath);
                    return;
                }
                for (i in json.data) {
                    currentFolder = json.data[i];

                    if (currentFolder.name == dirs[1]) {
                        found = currentFolder;
                        if (dirs.length > 2) {
                            lsdir(dirs.slice(2, dirs.length).join("/"), originalpath, currentFolder, callback);
                        } else {
                            callback(currentFolder, originalpath);
                            return;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    } else if (dirs.length > 0) {
        request(folder.upload_location + "/?access_token=" + at, function(err, res, body) {
            json = JSON.parse(body);
            var found = false;
            if (dirs.length == 1) {
                callback(json, originalpath);
            } else {
                for (i in json.data) {
                    currentFolder = json.data[i];

                    if (currentFolder.name == dirs[0]) {
                        lsdir(dirs.slice(1, dirs.length).join("/"), originalpath, currentFolder, callback);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        });
    }
}
```

---

```
lsdir("/vpsSync/", null, null, function(folder, originalpath) {
            console.log(("Directory contents of " + originalpath).bold);
            console.log(folder.data.map(function(arr) {
                if (arr.type == "folder") {
                    return arr.name + "/";
                }
                return arr.name;
            }).join("\n"));
        });
```

[image]

Is there a way to reduce the recursion (or remove it completly)? The Micro$ft servers are really slow (3-5 secs per request!)

Thank you all and enjoy the 215GB of OneDrive :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider using our just-announced API, which has the ability to do sync.

http://onedrive.github.io/items/view_changes.htm

If you start the sync operation from the point at which you want to begin traversing the hierarchy, and do not provide a token, it should return you a complete view. For larger hierarchies you will still need to make multiple requests (based on the value of "@changes.hasMorechanges" and "@odata.nextLink") but that will still be far fewer than one per folder.

Comment: Awesome! I'll take a look and try to reach my objective.
Thank you Brad!

P.S: Finally, the API relative to path. You saved my recursion (and of course your bandwidth :P)

Comment: is there any problem in you API?
When receiving an error the JSON is formatted, otherwise it isn't (it gives me problem while parsing with JSON.parse(string) )

http://pastebin.com/yASSMUxV
Could you check?

Comment: Interesting that we're inconsistent with the formatting, I'll look in to that. However, both appear to be valid JSON. Does the parse failure give you any indication as to where it's tripping up?

Comment: Found the problem: the JSON includes some unwanted chars (like 0xEF 0xBB 0xBF)

I compared two JSON files (the one on the left contains the response of OneDrive APIs and the one on the right is a hand-made JSON)

The first one gives me `SyntaxError: Unexpected token`, the second one is parsed correctly.

[Here's the Hexdump](http://i.imgur.com/3b4EQL9.png)

Comment: Looks like a BOM - perhaps it's not reporting the correct charset in the content type. Thanks a lot for pointing this out!

Comment: You're welcome. Thank you for driving me on the right way with the new API. I'm still discovering it all, seems nice (and of course is better than the v5.0, because I don't have to recourse into infinite directories)